# Evaluate $\int x^x \ln x\, dx$

Tags: integration, power-series

The integral $$\int x^x \ln x\, dx= ?$$
I know of the integral $\int x^x dx$ can be further simplified as $\int e^{x\ln x} dx$. And this requires identity to simplify. What about the product in the integral $\int x^x\ln x\,dx=\int e^{x\ln x}\ln x\, dx.$ Is there any identity to be used for this one.

Answer (score 8):

$$\int x^x (\ln x +1-1) dx= \int e^{x\ln x}(\ln x+1)dx -\int x^x dx$$
$$=\int e^{x\ln x} (x\ln x)'dx -\int x^x dx = e^{x\ln x}-\int x^x dx=x^x -\int x^x dx$$
There is now way to solve the last integral.

Comment: Yeah. That's very good approach. Now I can deal with the $\int x^xdx.$ This, I know how to deal with  it.

Comment: You want power series?

Comment: Yes fort the unresolved integral above. I have seen it somewhere how to do it, but I have to think deep again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Define $g(x) = x^x$. Then $\ln g(x) = x\ln x$ and differentiating both sides
$$\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\ln x+1,$$
which means $g'(x) = x^x(\ln x + 1)$. Now, up to a constant
$$x^x = \int g'(x)\,dx  = \int x^x \ln x \,dx + \int x^x\,dx$$
thus
$$\int x^x \ln x\,dx=x^x-\int x^x\,dx. $$

Comment: Or you can find $g'(x)$ directly: $(x^x)'=(\exp(x\ln x))'=\exp(x\ln x)\times(x \ln x)'=\exp(x\ln x)(1\times \ln x + \frac1x \times x)=\exp(x\ln x)(\ln x + 1))=x^x(\ln x + 1)$